# Highlighting cell when value is being calculated (+ interval)

Tags: jquery

So i'm making a table that displays some random numbers in HTML text input fields, and I want to make it so that:

when a button is clicked, each cell has a 300 millisecond delay, and in this time period the cell changes color, inserts the random number, and then returns the cell color to its original value, and moves on to the next cell, creating a nice visual display.

My main issue with this is that i'm not sure how to make each cell highlight itself when its' values are being calculated. I was thinking of putting "*this*" in the *gen()* function but I lose it there. Any help would be tremendously appreciated!

Example:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" id="rand1"></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="rand2"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" id="rand3"></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="rand4"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input type="button" id="generate">
```

jQuery

```
$('#generate').click(function() {
    randomise();
});

function randomise() {
    $('#rand1').val(gen(20,60));
    $('#rand2').val(gen(30,50));
    $('#rand3').val(gen(20,100));
    $('#rand4').val(gen(40,60));
}

function gen(x, y) {
    var rand = Math.round((Math.random() * (y-x)) + x);
    return rand;
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why each input gets a different random value range?

Comment: I was making a workout program that would randomise how many sets/reps i'd do each morning when waking up. Thought that would motivate me to exercise a bit more :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
  $("td").css({border: "1px solid #ccc"})
    $(".rand").css({opacity: 0});
    $('#generate').click(function() {
        randomise();
    });

    function randomise() {
        var myArray = [gen(20,60), gen(15,50), gen(10,25), gen(300, 400)]
        $(".rand").each(function(index){
            $(".rand").css({opacity: 0});
            var delay = (index+1)*300;
            $(this).val(myArray[index]).delay(delay).css({backgroundColor: "#000", color: "#fff"}).animate({opacity:1}, function(){
                $(this).delay(delay).css({backgroundColor: "#fff", color:"#000"})
            });
        });
    }

    function gen(x, y) {
        var rand = Math.round((Math.random() * (y-x)) + x);
        return rand;
    }
```

Here is working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lajon/09qg73mr/1/)

Comment: Thank you so much for putting time into this! There was one problem with the fiddle that i was stumped by and that was the inability to insert different "gen(x, y)"s into the mix, so i sorted it out with an array. Heres the updated fiddle! https://jsfiddle.net/09qg73mr/2/

Comment: I am glad I could help. For your array you don't have to create another variable `i = 0`, you can use index from `each()` loop like that: `$(this).val(array[index])`. See updated answer.

Comment: Very neat. Thank you so much!